# auto-increment a field in MS Access 2016 form

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I'm building a basic form and would like an id field in the form to auto-increment when the user opens the form (or could be a different event as well, just figured this is simplest).

I've written the following vb code, but there seems to be an issue:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()    

    lngNextID = DMax("[portfolio_id]", "table1") + 1
    Form 1.portfolio_id = lngNextID

End Sub
```

table1 is the table I want the vb to look up for the next increment.
The name of my form is 'Form 1' and the field in that form that I'm looking to autoincrement is portfolio_id.

Any advice/modifications would be helpful, thank you.

Comment: Why don't you just use Autonumber type field? Exactly what is the issue - error message, wrong result, nothing happens? Syntax referencing form is not correct. Use Me.portfolio_id, However, if you load form with existing records, this code will replace existing data. Is this a multi-user db? Beware possibility of simultaneous users generating same ID.

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
Forms("Form 1").portfolio_id = lngNextID
```

or the simpler:

```
Me!portfolio_id = lngNextID
```

However, that will update the opening record, so try setting the *DefaultValue* (a string):

```
Me!portfolio_id.DefaultValue = "'" & lngNextID "'"
```